Structure factor of FCC
I know that the structure factor of FCC in conventional basis is
\begin{equation}
S=1+e^{iπ(h+k)}+e^{iπ(l+k)}+e^{iπ(h+l)}
\end{equation}
Now if I change the basis to the primitive basis, the new structure factor will be $S=4f$, since in this new basis the positions of atoms are $(0, 0,0) $, $(1, 0,0) $ and so on.
What's going wrong here?

And how many atoms are there in a primitive cell for fcc?

What is $f$  in your formula ?

To make a previous comment more clear: in the conventional square unit cell for FCC, there are four lattice points. However, by definition, if you are using a primitive unit cell, then there is only one lattice point in the cell, so you need only consider one of them when computing the structure factor (which is of course then just trivial).

@march but my point was that there are no absences in this basis - is that correct?

There are no systematic absences when you compute the structure factor using a primitive unit cell. In that case, the structure factor is equal to 1.

@march is it always going to be true for any lattice in its primitive basis? Doesn't that imply that the structure factor is basis dependent?

1/2 I guess it's not clear to me what your issue is, which is why I haven't written an answer. Systematic absences are a consequence of using a non-primitive unit cell to compute scattering properties, and so you have to compute a structure factor that ends up having zeroes. If you use a primitive unit cell to compute scattering properties, and there is only one atom per lattice site (and therefore one atom per unit cell), you necessarily get a trivial structure factor, since there can be no extra interference because there's only one lattice point in a primitive unit cell.

2/2 However, if there is a basis in the primitive unit cell (e.g., two carbon atoms in the fcc primitive unit cell for diamond), there can be interference between atoms in the basis, meaning that the structure factor will be non-trivial (you can get absences due to destructive interference between the two atoms in the basis). Does this address your question?
